# How to make asynchronous HTML requests with Javascript that include cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies, asynchronous

I would like to make multiple HTML requests that are happening at the same time (not one after another) with Javascript. I would also like to add cookies to that requests. It seems that AJAX would be the way to go but I'd like to see example code that includes cookies and also the asynchronous aspect.

I'd like to use plain Javascript but am also open to solutions using jQuery or other frameworks.

Comment: Are you trying to add a cookie in addition to what the browser will send?

Comment: Yes, I want to add like custom made cookies.

Comment: Are the examples you've found so far *not* asynchronous?

Comment: For clarification, here is what I want to do:

Make HTML request to URL A, add a certain cookie to that request and wait for reply;

At the same time, I want to make a HTML request to URL B, also add a certain cookie to that request and wait for reply.

Doing the above for an arbitrary number of URLs.

Comment: And is this to the same domain or cross domain?

Comment: It would be cross domain.

Answer (score 1):

Any request from a browser, including AJAX, will automatically carry cookies set for the target domain.